# Access to my raspberry pi with samba over the internet

Tags: pi-2, samba

Is there a way to have access my samba on the raspberry pi over the internet? To have acces through my normal file browser? I don't want to use FileZilla, just a normal file system.
Couldn't find a tutorial.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think this question fits http://unix.stackexchange.com/ better as it is not specific to the RaspberryPi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking Samba over the Internet is a bad idea. See here:

https://superuser.com/questions/544393/samba-access-shares-from-internet

If you tunneled the traffic through SSH, that would be much more secure. This is somewhat problematic though, as Windows does not allow you to specify a port when accessing a Samba share. There are workarounds as described here:

https://www.bitvise.com/file-sharing

This could prove problematic, however, if you are not an administrator on your remote workstation.